# Does GWT JSNI support callbacks?

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am building a GWT app that uses Web SQL Local Storage (
http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/ ).
The problem is that the Web SQL API uses callback functions as
arguments.

Is it possible to pass "Java" callbacks to JSNI?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it does:

```
private static native void doThingWithCallback() /*-{
  var self = this;
  var callbackFn = $entry(function(val) {
    self.@com.your.package.AClass.aMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(val);
  });
  $wnd.someApiThatTakesACallback(callbackFn);
}-*/;
```

Two things to remember:

1. `$entry()` reminds GWT to keep track of the code when using the debugger.
2. `var self = this` keeps the reference to `this` inside the function -- otherwise `this` will be the function itself...

Comment: You are supposed to have :: before the method name: self.@com.your.package.AClass::aMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(val);

Comment: is this a javascript method or a java method? javascript doesn't have 'private static' and java doesn't have 'var'.

Comment: @ClickUpvote it's a GWT native method, which let's you write native JS in you GWT Java code.